# Object array replace string values for specific property

Tags: typescript

I need to replace some string values the user defines for an array of objects, but apply the rules only for some of the properties. For example if I have the following array:

```
[
{Name: 'Name1 Address', Fullname: 'Fullname1', Address: 'Address1'},
{Name: 'Name2', Fullname: 'Fullname2', Address: 'Address2'},
{Name: 'Name3', Fullname: 'Fullname3', Address: 'Address3'}
]
```

and the user wants to replace the word 'address' with 'test' but only for the 'Name' property, then the array should look like this:

```
[
{Name: 'Name1 test', Fullname: 'Fullname1', Address: 'Address1'},
{Name: 'Name2', Fullname: 'Fullname2', Address: 'Address2'},
{Name: 'Name3', Fullname: 'Fullname3', Address: 'Address3'}
]
```

Since the array can contain a lot of objects and the user can add rules for whatever property they want, how can I replace these values without having to go through each item and use string replace for a specific property?

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm misinterpreting "go through each item and use string replace for a specific property", but it certainly seems like anything you do will have to do that; what alternatives are there? I mean, does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WyXRbm) meet your needs?  It's not clear what you want to do if you have two rules that modify the same property; should the rules apply successively or "at once"?  Like, does `"x"`→`"y"` and `"y"`→`"z"` on the same property turn `"box"` into `"boy"` or `"boz"`?  How should we proceed here?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you need a type that does this, or if you need a function that does this, so here's both:

```js
const x = [
    { Name: 'Name1 Address', Fullname: 'Fullname1', Address: 'Address1' },
    { Name: 'Name2', Fullname: 'Fullname2', Address: 'Address2' },
    { Name: 'Name3', Fullname: 'Fullname3', Address: 'Address3' },
] as const;

// Replacing it within the types
type ReplacedAddress<T extends typeof x> = [
    ...{
        [K in keyof T]: {
            // This assumes that all the "Name" properties follow the same format.
            Name: T[K]['Name'] extends `Name${infer I} Address` ? `Name${I} test` : T[K]['Name'];
            Fullname: T[K]['Fullname'];
            Address: T[K]['Address'];
        };
    }
];

let a: ReplacedAddress<typeof x>;

// Actually replacing it
const replaceAddress = <T extends typeof x>(items: T) => {
    return items.map((item) => ({
        ...item,
        Name: item.Name.replace(/Address/g, 'test'),
    })) as ReplacedAddress<T>;
};

console.log(replaceAddress(x));
```

Compiled:

```js
"use strict";
const x = [
    { Name: 'Name1 Address', Fullname: 'Fullname1', Address: 'Address1' },
    { Name: 'Name2', Fullname: 'Fullname2', Address: 'Address2' },
    { Name: 'Name3', Fullname: 'Fullname3', Address: 'Address3' },
];
let a;
const replaceAddress = (items) => {
    return items.map((item) => ({
        ...item,
        Name: item.Name.replace(/Address/g, 'test'),
    }));
};
console.log(replaceAddress(x));
```